# Using enum in a Class to specify value options for user input

Tags: c++, class, input, enums

I have developed the Allergy program (see code below) to record information about an allergy provided by user input. I want to add another option for the user to input the "severity" of the allergy based on predetermined values.

I want to create an enum to hold the values the user should choose from. Here is what I have so far, but I'm just ignorant when it comes to enum and just how exactly it should be implemented.

Allergy.hpp:

```
#ifndef Allergy_hpp
#define Allergy_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


class Allergy {
public:
    enum severity {mild, moderate, severe};

    Allergy();
    Allergy(string, string, list <string>);
    ~Allergy();

    //getters
    string getCategory() const;
    string getName() const;
    list <string> getSymptom() const;


private:

    string newCategory;
    string newName;
    list <string> newSymptom;



};

#endif /* Allergy_hpp */
```

Allergy.cpp:

```
include "Allergy.hpp"

Allergy::Allergy(string name, string category, list <string> symptom){
    newName = name;
    newCategory = category;
    newSymptom = symptom;
}

Allergy::~Allergy(){

}

//getters
string Allergy::getName() const{
    return newName;
}

string Allergy::getCategory() const{
    return newCategory;
}


list <string> Allergy::getSymptom() const{
    return newSymptom;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Allergy.hpp"

using namespace std;


int main() {
    string name;
    string category;
    int numSymptoms;
    string symptHold;
    list <string> symptom;

    cout << "Enter allergy name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter allergy category: ";
    getline(cin, category);
    cout << "Enter number of allergy symptoms: ";
    cin >> numSymptoms;

    for(int i = 0; i < numSymptoms; i++){
        cout << "Enter symptom # " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> symptHold;
        symptom.push_back(symptHold);
    }

    Allergy Allergy_1(name, category, symptom);
    cout << endl << "Allergy Name: " << Allergy_1.getName() << endl <<
    "Allergy Category: " << Allergy_1.getCategory() <<  endl <<
    "Allergy Symptoms: ";

    for(auto& s : Allergy_1.getSymptom()){
        cout << s << ", ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize a loop, and a series of if statements to evaluate an enum value from a string. Unfortunatly unlike some language, enum's don't come with a string representation of their name. A sample of how to do this would be:

```
enum MyEnum{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
};

int main()
{
    bool isParsed=false;
    std::string line("");
    MyEnum myEnum;
    std::cout<<"Please enter your selection: ";
    while(!isParsed&&std::getline(std::cin,line)){
        if(line == "Value1"){
            isParsed = true;
            myEnum = Value1;
        }
        else if(line == "Value2"){
            isParsed = true;
            myEnum = Value2;
        }
        else if(line == "Value3"){
            isParsed = true;
            myEnum = Value3;
        }else{
            std::cout<<"Selection invalid, please enter a new selection: ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this helped me out! Is my use of enum correct? All the examples I see really just talk about declaration and I don't really see an implementation.

Comment: I would say in general your usage of enum is a good one. Any time that you have a list of values numerical such as that, an enum is usually a good possibility to model it. (Otherwise with something like `int severity` you will likely be using a fair amount of _magic numbers_, which are generally better to avoid.)